# what is the purpose of @Nonbinding annotation in a Qualifier supposed to be in Java EE7?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-7, inject

I am reading through the `CDI` injections in JavaEE 7 particularly using `@Qualifier` and `@Produces` to inject a `custom Data type` into a bean.

I have the following code taken from [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html) towards ends of the page.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface HttpParam {
   @Nonbinding public String value();
}

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

class HttpParams {
   @Produces @HttpParam("") 
   String getParamValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
      ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
      return request.getParameter(ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(HttpParam.class).value());
   }
}
```

And this qualifier could be used in the following way:

```
@HttpParam("username") @Inject String username;
@HttpParam("password") @Inject String password;
```

My question is :

1. what does `@Nonbinding` annotation mean? and why is it needed?
2. Should the method signature should always be like this `@Nonbindng public String value();`. The reason I ask this is I have seen several different examples but they all have the same signature. That is the following allowed:

```
public @interface HttpParam {
       @Nonbinding public int value();
    }
```

3. can I have more than one method defined in the interface. That is, is the following allowed or not?

```
 public @interface HttpParam {
       @Nonbinding public String value();
       @Nonbinding public int value1();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

1. By default, qualifier arguments are considered for matching bean qualifiers to injection point qualifiers. A `@Nonbinding` argument is not considered for matching.
2. In this case, the bean produced by the producer method has qualifier `@HttpParam("")`. If the argument were binding (i.e. not `@Nonbinding`), `@HttpParam("")` would not match `@HttpParam("username")` on the injection point.
3. You can have any number of qualifier arguments, binding or non-binding.

See [Typesafe resolution](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#performing_typesafe_resolution) in the CDI specification.

Comment: is it possible to give an example with Binding and Non-binding and show how it differs. That will be very helpful please

Comment: I was experiencing the exact behavior you have described in 2nd explanation when trying to use Interceptor binding with parameterized Annotations. I was desperate to find a solution to it. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.